# command line not working when run from vba

Tags: vba, command-prompt, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a file via my VBA code. I'm using 7z command line to unzip the file. However the command works when run from normal command prompt but the same command is not working when run via VBA code.

```
Command:
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "C:\Users\Public\AppData\Local\Temp\Sample.zip"
```

For further understanding, I'm trying to extract a docx file and that is why I am renaming it to .zip and then extracting.

```
Sub tst()
Dim MyFile As String, Outdir As String, Cmdstr As String
MyFile = Chr(34) & "c:\TMP\ratings.gz" & Chr(34)
Outdir = Chr(34) & "c:\tmp\0" & Chr(34)
Cmdstr = "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" & " e " & MyFile & " -o" & Outdir
Debug.Print Cmdstr
Call Shell(Cmdstr, 1)
End Sub
```

I've used this type of function (similar) to unzip the file.

Comment: Can you show some of your VBA code surrounding your command code?

Comment: Sub tst()
Dim MyFile As String, Outdir As String, Cmdstr As String
MyFile = Chr(34) & "c:\TMP\ratings.gz" & Chr(34)
Outdir = Chr(34) & "c:\tmp\0" & Chr(34)
Cmdstr = "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" & " e " & MyFile & " -o" & Outdir
Debug.Print Cmdstr
Call Shell(Cmdstr, 1)
End Sub


I've used this type of function (similar) to unzip the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing proper quoting, should be

```
Cmdstr = """c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe""" & " e " & MyFile & " -o" & Outdir
```

The *Command Line Version* of *7-Zip* is `7za.exe` rather than `7z.exe`.

I'm not sure about running CLI applications with `Shell` method but next could work:

```
Cmdstr = "cmd /D /C " & """full path to 7za\7za.exe""" & " e " & MyFile & " -o" & Outdir
```

**Edit**. To retain folder structure, use *7z* with `x` command rather than `e` command. While the `e`  command copies all extracted files to one directory, the `z` command extracts files from an archive with their full paths in the current directory, or in an output directory if specified. So you could define `Cmdstr` as follows:

```
Cmdstr = """c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe""" & " x " & MyFile & " -o" & Outdir
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first method is working but it is extracting all the files into a single directory and leads to loss in folder structure. The second method did not work when given as 7za.exe

I did some changes and it worked(atleast partially)
Cmdstr = cmd /D /C "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x C:\Users\mohankumard\AppData\Local\Temp\9781437706703-f010.zip

The above command extracts the file to C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates

Is there any way to change the extraction method?